# Nested REGEX capture

Tags: regex

I am using a data format like

```
{item 1 | item 2 | item 3}
```

to split items into an array for further processing.  This Regex pattern works fine for that:

```
`{([^}]+)}`
```

but I'd like to nest the groups like this

```
{This is {item 1 | item 2 | item 3} | This is not {item 5 | item 6 | item 7 }}
```

I've tried several things with no luck.  Is there a way to match the most inner items first then work outwards from there?

Comment: Without the regex engine info (Perl? BRE? grep?) this cannot be accurately answered.

Comment: I'm using PHP for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find only the most nested arrays:

```
{([^{}]*)}
```

If you want to find all outer arrays you can do like this (note that it will work only if it is PCRE)

```
{((?(?={)(?R)|[^}])*)}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option worked for me!   I don't plan on going deeper than one so I will just run the data through `{([^{}]*)}` first then `{([^}]+)}`

Comment: @kylefrischman Actually `{([^}]+)}` is incorrect if you have nested arrays. Check it on your example, it will give you `{This is {item 1 | item 2 | item 3}` and `{item 5 | item 6 | item 7 }`

Comment: Instead of using a conditional pattern to test if the next character is `{` or not, you can use this design: `{((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)}` that is simpler (the first alternation is tested ... first), or more efficient with an unrolled pattern: `{([^{}]*+(?:(?R)[^{}]*)*+)}`

Comment: Note also that PCRE isn't the only regex engine that supports conditional statements.